# iOS - WebRTC call going through without audio after a Phone call

Tags: ios, audio, webrtc

I'm developing a video call app based on WebRTC.

I'm facing a strange problem that when a phone call is progressing and if i'm trying to start a WebRTC call from my app, the call is establishing with only video, no audio (this is expected, as the Phone app gains the higher priority). But once the phone call is over, the WebRTC call should continue with audio and video and this is not happening. The audio seems not working even the audio resources are available. Any idea where it is going wrong? Any solution?

Comment: In a normal WebRTC call audio works properly? Also, when you are trying to make a WebRTC call with a phone call going on, what message do you get when you request audio?

Comment: Yes, normal WebRTC call works properly. When I'm trying webrtc call with on going phone call, i'm getting "ERROR: [0x40abb000] >aurioc> 807: failed: '!pri' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch, 16000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch, 16000 Hz, Int16>)"

Comment: So basically you are not getting access to the audio stream, I think you will have to request access to the audio stream once again after the phone call is over and then renegotiate.

Comment: How can I request access to the audio stream during a webrtc call?

Comment: Generally you should not allow the call to setup if any of the streams cannot be accessed. However, if you still wish to do that, you will have get the audio stream the same way you do at the start. I do not know iOS specific implementation, but in general WebRTC demands renegotiation whenever a stream is added or removed.